# Есть какой-либо компетентный источник, подтверждающий, что Вечный Город (Рим) - две с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Вечный Город (лат. aeterna urbs) — Рим.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4)

---

[Пантеон, Капитолий, Колизей, Римский Форум, Фонтан Треви... Рим. **Вечный Город**. Грандиозный, величественный, колосcальный. Этот город хочется описывать, пользуясь только самыми сильными эпитетами...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rrwhkd8p8VU)

---

[АНТИЧНЫЙ РИМ. Колизей (Colosseo) – символ Вечного Города, самая главная его достопримечательность и самая большая арена смерти в античные времена.](http://www.adriatic-travel.com.ua/%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_ru_251prod.html)

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Попрощавшись с теплоходом, направляюсь на вокзал, откуда на уже хорошо знакомой электричке еду в «Вечный Город».](http://uritsk.livejournal.com/32632.html)

---

[...В Вечный Город из Хельсинки.](https://vandrouki.ru/2017/norwegian-pryamyie-v-vechnyiy-gorod-iz-helsinki-za-5200-rubley-77e-tuda-obratno/)

---

[Намедни в Вечный Город прибыли гонцы из мятежной Умбрии и донесли превеселые известия.](https://www.facebook.com/gaiusanonimus/posts/1522783597742092:0)

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вечный город.** С латинского: Aeterna urbs (этэрна урбс). 
Впервые так назвал Рим римский поэт Тибулл (Альбий Тибулл,

[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/392/Вечный](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/392/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Обычно вторая прописная буква пишется: а) для обозначения условности названия;  б) в высоком смысле.

Здесь условности нет, это действительного город.

Comment: Любопытно, что в 30-томнике Ч. Диккенса — Вечный Город. Я посмотрел несколько изданий, начиная с 1958 г., до которых смог дотянуться с помощью Google. То же касается всех других изданий, включающих "Картины Италии". А по Вашей ссылке это точно название города, а не просто крылатая фраза? (Спрашиваю, потому что там и "вечный" — тоже со строчной.)

Comment: В Нацкорпусе чаще пишут Вечный город или вечный город, реже - Вечный Город.http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2%E5%F7%ED%FB%E9%20%E3%EE%F0%EE%E4&p=0

Comment: А, ребяты, как же ж жить?! Гриззли, у меня только одна приличная ссылка - первая: *Вечный Город (лат. aeterna urbs) — Рим.*